# How to programmatically interpret reStructuredText into docutil nodes?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I'm writing custom roles/directives in Sphinx, and I need to insert a node in which I interpret a text string as reStructuredText. Is there a way to do this?

I found this source http://agateau.com/2015/docutils-snippets which says how to use `docutils.nodes` classes to construct a doctree fragment programmatically, e.g.

```
class BulletList(Directive):
    def run(self):
        fruits = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas']

        lst = nodes.bullet_list()
        for fruit in fruits:
            item = nodes.list_item()
            lst += item
            item += nodes.paragraph(text=fruit)

        return [lst]
```

What I want to do is something like

```
:myrole:`this is *really* cool|trade|`
```

by doing this in conf.py:

```
def myrole(name, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={}, content=[]):
    # somehow convert the "text" parameter into docutils nodes
    # by interpreting it as RST
    nodes = ???? what goes here ???
    return nodes, []

def setup(app):
    app.add_role('myrole', myrole)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`self.state.nested_parse`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/markupapi.html#parsing-directive-content-as-rest) in your directive's `run()` method:

> Many directives will contain more markup that must be parsed. To do this, use one of the following APIs from the Directive.run() method:
>
> `self.state.nested_parse`
>
> `sphinx.util.nodes.nested_parse_with_titles()` – this allows titles in the parsed content.
>
> Both APIs parse the content into a given node. They are used like this:
>
> ```
> node = docutils.nodes.paragraph()
> # either
> nested_parse_with_titles(self.state, self.result, node)
> # or
> self.state.nested_parse(self.result, 0, node)
> ```

[This question about creating input using a `ViewList()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44084890/) may also be relevant.

I am not sure whether you can use this in a role. Obviously you won't be able to use the `self.` variant since roles are functions in any event.